# Generic collection loading from the generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have the following code, where i am trying to create a generic collection for the objects in my DAL (just an exercise, not actually production code).  My problem is that i want to use the type passed in's Read method (which is part of an interface that the classes implement).

I cannot create a `new T` so i dont have an instance of the object to work with, and i cant declare it as the base type, as i need the read method specified by the child of the base object.

Is this actually possible or am i barking up the wrong tree?

```
public class ItemDictionary<T> where T : ILoadable, DataItem
{

    public void Load()
    {
        using (IDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(_connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, _proc)) {
            Read(reader);
        }
    }

    bool Read(IDataReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read) 
        {
            T item = default(T);            //Here be the problem

            if (item.Read(reader)) 
            {
                this.Add(item.Guid, item);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}

public class ExampleObject : DataItem, ILoadable
{

    bool Read(IDataReader reader)
    {
        _var1 = reader.getString(0);
        _var2 = reader.getString(1);
        _var3 = reader.getString(2);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not have a default constructor on the type(s) held by the collection and add the new() directive to the where T : directive?

```
public class ItemDictionary<T> where T : ILoadable, DataItem, new()
```

and then:-

```
    T item = new T();
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was missing!
It even worked in VB.net :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me *why* you can't use `new T()` (with an appropriate constraint on `T`). It's also not clear to me why you're using explicit interface implementation, and why your `ILoadable` interface has a method called `ILoadable`, mind you.

Is the problem that you can't always guarantee to have a parameterless constructor in the object type? If that's the case, you'll certainly need *something* to create instances of `T`. Perhaps you actually need to separate `T` from its factory, perhaps with another interface:

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    // Roughly matching your current API
    bool TryRead(IDataReader reader, out T);

    // Simpler if you can just throw an exception on error
    T Read(IDataReader reader);
}
```

Then you can just pass an `IFactory<T>` implementation into your `ItemDictionary<T>` constructor.